# fgets instead of gets

Tags: c, count, fgets, cpu-word, gets

I made a program to count a given word in a sentence. When i try to run it through the compiler it say ''gets is deprecated''. So i replaced gets with fgets, but it will output 0 with every word and sentence. How can i fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>


void gotoNextWord();

char str[1026],w[1026];
int slen, wlen, wcount, i, j;



int main()
{

    fgets(str, 1026, stdin);
    fgets(w, 1026, stdin);

    slen = strlen(str);
    wlen = strlen(w);

    i = j = wcount = 0;

    if(w[i] == 0)
    {
        printf("Please specify a program argument.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        while(i<slen)
        {

            if (str[i] == w[0])
            {
                for(j=0; j<wlen; j++)
                {
                    if(str[i+j] != w[j])
                    {
                        gotoNextWord();
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(j == wlen)
                {
                    if(isspace(str[i+j])||ispunct(str[i+j])||str[i+j]=='\0')
                    {
                        wcount++;
                        i += j;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                gotoNextWord();
            }
            i++;
        }
        printf("%d\n",wcount);

    }
    return 0;
}

void gotoNextWord()
{
    while(isspace(str[i]) == 0 && ispunct(str[i] == 0 && str[i] != '\0'))
        i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A difference between `gets()` and `fgets()` is that `fgets()` retains a final `'\n'` and `gets()` does not.

The "word" code is now looking for contains a `'\n'`.

Drop the potential `'\n'` and continue with previous code.

```
fgets(str, 1026, stdin);
str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = '\0';

fgets(w, 1026, stdin);
w[strcspn(w, "\n")] = '\0';
```

---

Recommend style/code change when using `fgets()`

```
// fgets(str, 1026, stdin);
if (fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin) == NULL) return -1;
```